# In WPF how to update an observablecollection without reopen/refresh the whole page?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using some radiobuttons to navigate pages in a WPF MainWindow. One of the pages has an observablecollection as a table. Somehow after an update the values on the UI only change when i reopen this page, like i switch to another page then come back or i simply click its radiobutton. I have bound it like:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RunLabels}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="10" Foreground="#999"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="14" Margin="0,3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Here is my variable

```
    public class LabelModel:NotifyBase
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; this.NotifyChanged(); }
    }
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; this.NotifyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

And this

```
        ObservableCollection<LabelModel> runLabels {  get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LabelModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<LabelModel> RunLabels
    {
        get { return runLabels; }
        set
        {
            runLabels = value;
            this.NotifyChanged();
        }
    }
```

with

```
        public MonitorViewModel() 
    {


        RunLabels = new ObservableCollection<LabelModel>()
        {
            new LabelModel { Text = "Status", Value = OPCVariables.auto},
            new LabelModel { Text = "Operation Time", Value = "10h" },
            new LabelModel { Text = "Stand-by Time", Value = "Run" },
            new LabelModel { Text = "Failure Time", Value = "1h" },
            new LabelModel { Text = "Life Circle", Value = "Good" },
            new LabelModel { Text = "Next Service", Value = "5000h" },
        };
```

I renamed INotifyPropertyChanged to NotifyBase.
How i can update the UI without reopening the current page?

Comment: Can you please also show the code where you update the `RunLabels` collection? Do you update also the properties `Text` and `Value`? If yes, does your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @KlausGütter i did use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: What is `NotifyBase`?

Comment: Is your property `Runlabel` (with lower case l and without s) meant to be the same as the `RunLabels` in your binding?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes that was a typo here in stackoverflow edit form. Its actually working fine, but i must reopen the page to "refresh" the UI. Other controls on the same page dont have this problem

Comment: And again: what is `NotifyBase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RunLabel` type, or whatever it's called, should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever you set the `Text` and `Value` properties:

```
public class RunLabel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

It doesn't matter whether you're using an `ObservableCollection<T>` or any other kind of `IEnumerable<T>` as far as updating the properties of the individual items in the collection is concerned.

Comment: I'm using INotifyPropertyChanged , pls see ablove, i edited the question. The value is updating but i need somehow to refresh the windows so i can see the change in UI.

Comment: But how and where are you updating the properties?

Comment: its updating after i reopen that page :(

Comment: When do you expect it to update?

Comment: right away when the value changes, its like a live monitor to show a status of a machine

Comment: Again: How and where does the value change...? Where do you set the property in your code?

Comment: This answer should be correct. I believe OP is not raising property changed events correctly; I cannot tell if the 'NotifyChanged()' method is calling the property changed event with reference to the property that has changed.